# Difficulty (2) in understanding thm4.2 in Israel Gohberg.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, operator-theory

The theorem is given in the following picture:

[image]

I did not understand the proof of conversly in the following picture, why $\langle v-w,z\rangle = 0$?

[image]

Could anyone explain this for me please?

Answer (score 1):

You have $\langle w , \varphi_k \rangle = \sum_{k=1}^n \langle v, \varphi_j\rangle \, \langle \varphi_j, \varphi_k\rangle = \sum_{k=1}^n \langle v, \varphi_j\rangle\, \delta_{jk} = \langle v, \varphi_j\rangle$.
Here, $\delta_{jk}$ is Kronecker's delta.
Now, $\langle v - w , z \rangle$ follows since
$\langle v - w, \varphi_k\rangle = \langle v, \varphi_j\rangle - \langle v, \varphi_j\rangle = 0$.